# "TypeError: form.set is not a function" Java can't access FormData's functions

Tags: java

I beg pardon for my english skills in advance.

I don't know enough about JS coding, but i have checked that code (the one below) using Mozilla Firefox Developer Console and that has been successfully executed (I mean i have got correct response from the server). The following JS code i have written:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
form = new FormData(); 
form.set("faculty",50029); 
form.set("kurs",4); 
form.set("group",52543); 
form.set("ok","Show\""); 
form.set("group_el",0); 
url = 'myUrl'; //i just have deleted this, that works fine
request.open("POST", url); 
request.send(form);
```

The problem is when i try use this code from Java, i get the error that looks like that:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: form.set is not a function. (In 'form.set("faculty",50029)', 'form.set' is undefined)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:157)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1509)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:973)
    at JavFx.lambda$initAndShowGUI$1(JavFx.java:177)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

The code which does it in Java:

```
jButton.addActionListener(e -> { //Execute JS code
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("request = new XMLHttpRequest();");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("form = new FormData();");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("form.set(\"faculty\",50029);");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("form.set(\"kurs\",4);");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("form.set(\"group\",52543);");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("form.set(\"ok\",\"Показать\\\"\");");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("form.set(\"group_el\",0);");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("url = 'https://cabinet.sut.ru/raspisanie_all_new?type_z=1';");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("request.open(\"POST\", url);");
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("request.send(form);");
            });
        });
```

I work at IntellijIdea.
All that code is executed with WebEngine.

Comment: Java != JavaScript.

Comment: amm) i know that)
I'm trying use JS code via WebEngine's executeScript() method, as you can see.

Comment: webview implementation of javascript might differ fro mth e one that works in the browser , it could also be that you cant use variables from a differnet executeScript method (try putting them all in one string ) on top of that you could try using 'let ' before declaring a new variable again not sure of the javascript implementation

Comment: however since all youre doing is call a httpRequest you might as well jsut do it from the java code itslef oO

Comment: no need to push it to the webview which will then execute javascript which will push it back to java to call a request

Comment: thx for answer, i've already checked that i can use declaration and using of the same variable in different executeScript calls. I will try use 'let' and reply

Comment: yes i could, but i would like to try this way first)

Comment: @jonathanHeindl unfortunately adding 'let' changes nothing even if i place every statement in one line